# How to trigger an entity's animation declared in .reality file?

Tags: swift, xcode, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

In `Reality Composer` I created `MyScene.rcproject`, in MyScene I created a panel and its spin animation, the action sequence begins when its notification is posted from code.

[image]

When it's come to trigger the animation from `MyScene.rcproject` it works like I expect:

```
self.sceneAnchor = try MyScene.loadMyScene()
sceneAnchor.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
sceneAnchor.notifications.spin.post()
```

But when I export `MyScene.rcproject` file to `MyScene.reality` and I implement it into another app project:

```
panelEntity = try? ModelEntity.load(named: "MyScene")
sceneAnchor.addChild(panelEntity)
```

I can't find any method to trigger the spin animation. Is it possible to trigger entity's animation, inside `MyScene.reality` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RealityKit 2.0, if using `.reality` file instead of `.rcproject`, ***Notifications*** class is inaccessible.

```
public private(set) lazy var notifications = A.Scene.Notifications(root: self))
```